# Distributed Systems and Network OSs (Theoretical)

Tags: network-programming, operating-system, distributed, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I have a small question that buggers me a bit!!

A. Tanenbaum in his book, "Distributed Systems"  is defining this: "A distributed system is: A collection of independent computers that appears to its users as a single coherent system."

My question: Could a Network Operating System, that provides local services to remote computers, be considered    as a distributed system by the above definition ? Explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean a network OS as it's defined by [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_operating_system) than I'd say no, since it's running only on one machine.

> A distributed system is: *A **collection** of independent **computers*** that appears to its users as a single coherent system.

So it has to be a collection of computers. For instance - Google Search is a distributed system. For a user it is one search box but inside google dozens or even hundreds of machines are activated / used when you search for something.

But maybe you mean something else by the term network OS. In this case you have to ask yourself if the network communications are explicit (visible to the user - the user needs to call one server, ...) or implicit (hidden from the user, load balancing, ...)

Another famous quote comes from Leslie Lamport:

> You know you have a distributed system when the crash of a computer you’ve never heard of stops you from getting any work done.

This basically describes something similar - that the communication between the computers is implicit and the user doesn't know which servers are used for which tasks. Or even that there are multiple nodes, since they maybe only communicate to the load balancer.

**Update:**

While the top still stands, looking at the comment, there are two different things - Network OS and Distributed OS. Looking at [wikipedias description of Distributed OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_operating_system) this is - as the name suggests a Distributed System, according to Tanenbaums definition. The Network OS isn't.

Comment: Hey thanks for your contribution. I was reading this .pdf i found online http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~mosse/cs2510/class-notes/intro.pdf . On page 13 it says a few thing about Networks OSs but i really cant decide, at all!

Comment: @Andr.Ludw. I've updated it, since you asked about the Network OS, but in the slides you are referencing the term mentioned is Distributed OS which is - as the name suggests a Distributed System (even according to Tanenbaums definition)

Answer (score 1):

**Simply No**

Because of the following differences between DOS and NOS:

1. System Image

> In case of a NOS, the users view the distributed computing system as a collection of distinct machines connected by a communication subsystem.
>   On the other hand, a DOS hides existence of multiple computers and provides a single-system image to its users **(virtual uniprocessor)**.

Autonomy

> Computers in a NOS, have more autonomous powers than computers in a DOS.

Fault tolerance

> NOS provides little or no fault tolerance capability, thus users are affected in NOS. But on other hand, DOS provides fault tolerance; and not users but performance is affected in DOS.